# How do I dynamically centre one svg element on another with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Given two svg elements that could be nested multiple times, have different transformations applied, and even be in different [svg fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermCurrentSVGDocumentFragment), how would I move one (with javascript) so that it is centred on the other?

For the example below, I would like to move the red square so it is centred inside the blue square (without changing anything else about its shape).

**Note:** *The javascript should be somewhat generic, so that it will still work after changing some of the transform attributes anywhere below*

```js
var big_rect = document.getElementById('big_rect');
var small_rect = document.getElementById('small_rect');
var sm_box = small_rect.getBBox();
console.log(sm_box);

// get center of rect in its coordinate system
var pnt = big_rect.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
pnt.x = big_rect.x.baseVal.value + big_rect.width.baseVal.value/2;
pnt.y = big_rect.y.baseVal.value + big_rect.height.baseVal.value/2;

// following lines unrotate the smaller rect, 
// and don't center it on larger one anyway
/*
big_rect.parentNode.appendChild(small_rect);
small_rect.setAttribute('transform','translate(' + 
                         (pnt.x - sm_box.width / 2) + ',' +
                         (pnt.y - sm_box.height / 2) + ')'
                        );
*/
```

```html
<svg viewbox="50 50 250 250" height="250" width="250">
  <g transform="translate(10,10) scale(2.5)">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 500 500">
      <g transform="translate(30,30) scale(0.5)">
        <rect transform="translate(50,50)" id="big_rect" x=50 y=100 height=350 width=350 fill="blue" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g transform="scale(1.5) translate(15,15)">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 300 300">
      <g id="small_rect" transform="rotate(45)">
        <rect x="150" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="red" />
        <g>
    </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I immediately thought about something like `small_rect.setAttribute('transform', small_rect.getAttribute('transform') + ' translate(' + …` but the red rectangle disappeared when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your small_rect id is on the group element. you should target the rect element within the group.

Comment: That is not my issue.  I want the "small_rect" id on the group element.  I want to center any element (including a group) on another element (including another group).

Comment: there's another thing that I'm thinking could cause an issue possibly which is the nested svg element with a different viewbox, once you set a viewbox you change your bounding box therefore the transform property inherits the closest parent bounding box as global and any other nested transform will comply to that. Not sure if it solves your problem though...

Comment: @hyphenbash is correct.  If you are operating on the groups rather than the rects, then you are calculating the centre of the rect where it was *before* later transformations were applied. So the rects are not likely to end up centered w.r.t. one another in that situation.